# How to animate sliding-in text form left to right

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I already have a sliding text which slides in from the right side to the left but I do not succeed in it to make this work from the **left** to the right **side**.

So the `<h1>` is sliding in from the right side and is going to the left. And the `<h2>` should slide in from the left side and going to the right. The text should stay at the right side of the screen. Play the animation at the same time.

```css
h1 {
  -moz-animation-duration: 3s;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 3s;
  -moz-animation-name: slidein-left;
  -webkit-animation-name: slidein-left;
}

@-moz-keyframes slidein-left {
  from {
    margin-left: 100%;
    width: 300%
  }
  to {
    margin-left: 0%;
    width: 100%;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes slidein-left {
  from {
    margin-left: 100%;
    width: 300%
  }
  to {
    margin-left: 0%;
    width: 100%;
  }
}

h2 {
  -moz-animation-duration: 3s;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 3s;
  -moz-animation-name: slidein-right;
  -webkit-animation-name: slidein-right;
}

@-moz-keyframes slidein-right {
  from {
    margin-right: 100%;
    width: 300%
  }
  to {
    margin-right: 0%;
    width: 100%;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes slidein-right {
  from {
    margin-right: 100%;
    width: 300%
  }
  to {
    margin-right: 0%;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>I come from the right side</h1>
<h2 style="padding-right: 0px;">I come from the left side</h2>
```

How can i achieve this?
[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rs8dco4g/)

Comment: Do you want the H2 to come off the screen from left side? or to make it move from the left corner to right corner?

Comment: he should come from off the screen

Comment: Okay, Don't use margins to animate. check my answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set the `width` to `100%`. `text-align: right` the one you want to have on the right side.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

h1,
h2 {
  width: 100%;
}

h1 {
  animation: right_to_left 3s ease;
}

h2 {
  text-align: right;
  animation: left_to_right 3s ease;
}

@keyframes right_to_left {
  from {
    margin-left: 100%;
  }
  to {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes left_to_right {
  from {
    margin-left: -100%;
  }
  to {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>I come from the right side</h1>
<h2>I come from the left side</h2>
```

Comment: Well, i agree this works fine. but the text in the h2 should stay at the right side of the screen

Comment: You didn't mention that in your question. The answer is edited.

Answer (score 3):

Well, it's not generally recommended to use margins to animate. For css animations, you can use transform and translate properties.

Here's how you can do it using transform.

***css:***

```
@keyframes slidein-left {
    0% {
        transform: translateX(-100%);
    }
    100% {
        transform: translateX(0);
    }
}

@keyframes slidein-right {
    0% {
        transform: translateX(100%);
    }
    100% {
        transform: translateX(0);
    }
}

h1 {  
    animation: 3s slidein-right;
}

h2 {  
    animation: 3s slidein-left;
}
```

***HTML:***

```
<h1>I come from the right side</h1>
<h2>I come from the left side</h2>
```

Here's the fiddle : [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xcqysce5/)

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Why is it not recommended to use margins for a CSS animation?

Comment: @Sun due to performance issues. Here's a good article on it. https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/high-performance-animations/

Answer (score 0):

Or with jQuery and Css like this:

## JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("h1").css("margin-left", "10px");
$("h2").css("margin-left", ($("body").width() - $("h2").width()) + "px");
```

});

## CSS:

```
    body
 {
     overflow:hidden;
 }

 h1 {

       margin-left:4000px;
       white-space:nowrap;
       transition: margin 3s;
  }

  h2 {

       margin-left:-400px;
       width:400px;
       text-align:right;
       white-space:nowrap;
       transition: margin 3s;
  }
```

## HTML

```
<h1>I come from the right side</h1>
<h2>I come from the left side</h2>
```

Fiddle: [jsfiddle.net/rs8dco4g/8/](https://jsfiddle.net/rs8dco4g/8/)

The text stays on the right/left side.

Hope this helps