# How we can move CSS object from Right to Left using javascript?

Tags: javascript

*Hi, In javascript we have option of finding offSetRight position of Element and can move it  towards Left to Right side using setInterval method but i like to bring that object from right to left and i did not find any javascript method which i can use Here in my code , if you guys can take a look it would be great, also i like to mention i am new to Js so i hope people will go easy on me.*

P.s - CSS and Jquery not allowed for animation.

```
var e = document.getElementById("aDiv");
var s = 1;





function myInterval() {
    var eLeftPos = e.offsetLeft;
    //console.log(e.offsetLeft);
    e.style.left = (eLeftPos + s) + 'px';
    //console.log(e.style.left);



    var leftPos = (eLeftPos + s) >= 300

  if (leftPos) {
    function myInterval1() {
      var eTopPos = e.offsetTop;
      //console.log(e.offsetLeft);
      e.style.top = (eTopPos + s) + 'px';

      //console.log(e.style.top);

      if ((eTopPos + s) >= 100){
        clearInterval(internal1)

      }

    }

    var internal1 = setInterval(myInterval1, 100);


  }

    if ((eLeftPos + s) >= 300){

      clearInterval(internal)
    }
}
var internal = setInterval(myInterval, 100);
```

Comment: Add your HTML as well

Comment: I can but it is not of any use, we will be not using CSS for animation.

Comment: I you don't include your HTML, I cannot help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try Using CSS methods instead of Javascript. Try this:
[CSS Animation from Left to Right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41587802/css-animation-from-left-to-right)

or this: [How to animate sliding-in text form left to right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48033610/how-to-animate-sliding-in-text-form-left-to-right)

Comment: Yes but here it is not an option.